# How do I output additional PHP nested array values?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here's the output from my JSON feed:

```
"Data": [
    {
      "EventName": "EVENT NAME HERE",
      ...,
      "Items": [
        {
          "ItemId": 1460016,
          "ItemType": "Space",
          "Name": "Walking Track"
        },
        {
          "ItemId": 1460015,
          "ItemType": "Space",
          "Name": "Weight Room"
        },
        {
          "ItemId": 1464063,
          "ItemType": "Resource",
          "Name": "Fabric Chairs",
          "Qty": 10
        }
      ],
      ...
    },...
```

I'm able to output the EventName, etc. But how do I return a comma-separated list of item Names where the ItemType is 'Space'? Like this:

`Walking Track, Weight Room`

I've tried a number of combinations of PHP array functions -- but haven't been able to filter out the results.

### Edit

Nagwa's response got me halfway there -- but it didn't filter for ItemType = 'Space'. I then added a conditional, but still had to remove blank values. Here's what I ended up with. It works -- but is there a better method that I'm overlooking?

```
foreach ($arr['Data'] as $event) {
    $locations = array_map(function($item) {
        if ($item['ItemType'] == 'Space') {
            return $item['Name'];
        }
    }, $event['Items']);
    $locationsList = implode(', ', array_filter($locations));
    print $locationsList;
}
```

Comment: You can treat `$array['Items']` as an array, and then iterate over it with `foreach()`. From there you can build a new array based on a conditional on the `ItemType`.

Comment: Thought about this, but was hoping there might be a better way to filter the items array via PHP. Nagwa's response gets me closer. I didn't tried using array_map().

Comment: See my final solution above. Is there a better method?

Comment: @MathewSmith Can you share a proper JSON or var_export() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$names = array_map(function ($arr){
    return $arr['Name'];
}, $array['Data']['Items']);

$namesList = implode(', ', $names);
die($namesList);
```

Comment: This gets me halfway there -- but it doesn't filter for ItemType = 'Space'. Edited original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk()` to build your list. For each item, if the ItemType is 'Space', append the Name to your list of spaces.

```
$spaces = [];
foreach ($arr['Data'] as $event) {
    $locations = array_walk(
        $event['Items'],
        function($item) use (&$spaces) {
            if ($item['ItemType'] == 'Space') {
                $spaces[] = $item['Name'];
            }
        }
    );
    $locationsList = implode(', ', $spaces);
    print $locationsList; // Walking Track, Weight Room
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "is there a better method", you are asking for a more direct approach with less time complexity, then you will want an approach that doesn't perform more than one (nested) loop to isolate the column data, filter it, and delimit the strings with commas.

```
foreach ($arr['Data'] as $event) {
    /* ... echoing other $event data ... */
    echo array_reduce(
             $event['Items'],
             function($result, $item) {
                 if ($item['ItemType'] === 'Space') {
                     if (!$result) {
                         $result .= ', ';
                     }
                     $result .= $item['Name'];
                 }
                 return $result;
             },
             ''
         );
}
```

Using another "functional style" approach optimized for brevity will involve multiple functions which will use 3 loops ("under the hood"). For example:

```
foreach ($arr['Data'] as $event) {
    echo implode(
             ', ',
             array_column(
                 array_filter($event['Items'], fn($item) => $item['ItemType'] === 'Space'),
                 'Name'
             )
         );
}
```

Finally, you could use a classic nested loop, but the drawback of this approach is the declaration of a temporary variable being declared in the global scope.

```
foreach ($arr['Data'] as $event) {
    $itemNames = []
    foreach ($event['Items'] as $item) {
        if ($item['ItemType'] === 'Space') {
            $itemNames[] = $item['Name'];
        }
    }
    echo implode(', ', $itemNames);
}
```